# CKAN error 500 internal error on front page?

Tags: solr, wsgi, ckan

Any pages I make changes in CKAN always render a error 500. Recently, the homepage will not work. This is the traceback I get.

```
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170268 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170285 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 366, in _send_request
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170296 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]     timeout=self.timeout)
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170308 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170321 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170334 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170345 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170356 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170369 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170379 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170392 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.170405 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176] ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8983): Max retries exceeded with url: /solr/select/?sort=view_recent+desc&fq=%2Bcapacity%3Apublic+capacity%3A%22public%22&fq=%2Bsite_id%3A%221%22&fq=%2Bstate%3Aactive&facet.mincou$
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463679 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176] 2019-11-20 09:24:40,463 ERROR [pysolr] Failed to connect to server at 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select/?sort=score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&fq=owner_org%3A%22a515ac6d-0a66-4565-b727-914fd27b290a%22&fq=%2Bsite_id%3A%221%22&fq=%2Bst$
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463751 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463761 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 366, in _send_request
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463769 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]     timeout=self.timeout)
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463777 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463786 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463795 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463803 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463811 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463819 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.463827 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.464403 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176]     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
[Wed Nov 20 09:24:40.464420 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1217:tid 140172777490176] ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8983): Max retries exceeded with url: /solr/select/?sort=score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&fq=owner_org%3A%22a515ac6d-0a66-4565-b727-914fd27b290a%22&fq=%2
```

Does anyone know what caused the exact problem? Is it a wsgi error? I installed ckan from package so I do not know what exactly is wrong. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: I managed to fix it! I forgot to uncomment the entries I changed #solr_url to solr_url and #JETTY_HOST to JETTY_HOST.**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **ConnectionError**, Max retries exceeded when the CKAN tries to connect to your Solr instance.

Did you setup solr? If so, please check solr_url inside your .ini file, the current setup tries to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8983?

Comment: I did setup solr. I have set the localhost as my solr server, so I used http://127.0.0.1:89893/solr as my solr_url. What should I set it to?